# Spread argument in Typescript

Tags: typescript, event-bus

I'm making a EventBus in typescript, react.
But there is a type error in my code.

This is my code.

```
class _EventBus {
  private readonly bus: { [key: string | number]: () => void }
  constructor() {
    this.bus = {}
  }

  $off(id: string | number) {
    delete this.bus[id]
  }

  $on(id: string | number, callback: () => void) {
    this.bus[id] = callback
  }

  $emit(id: string | number, params: Array<string | number>) {
    if(this.bus[id]) {
      this.bus[id](...params) // A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
    }
  }
}

export const EventBus = new _EventBus()
```

The callback parameter has an error **A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.**

And I also tried this code.

`private readonly bus: { [key: string | number]: (params: Array<string | number>) => void }`

But this code has an eslint error **no-unused-vars**.

How can I make a event-bus like vue in typescript, react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the type definition of the `bus` field to the following

```js
private readonly bus: {
  [key: string | number]: (...params: Array<string | number>) => void;
};
```

You can find the working example in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-mclaren-pvgc6j?file=/src/index.ts)

And the link to the [TypeScript Rest Parameters and Arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters-and-arguments)

Comment: But this case has an eslint error **'params' is defined but never used.(no-unused-vars)** I don't want to remove no-unused-vars setting.

Comment: I don't think eslint can complain about that for the type definition. It seems like you've added `...params` in the wrong place. Could you, please, clarify where have you added it and where do you see this error?

Comment: I solved using "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"]. Previously, I used general "no-unused-vars". Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty much on point here. You can solve this problem by using a rest parameter as the argument of the function.

```
private readonly bus: { [key: string | number]: (...args: (string | number)[]) => void }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgPoFEBuBTAdgFwEIFd4BvYOOABwCcBLFSLNOCtSAEwHsNwBPOAIwIBccQnADaAazRch0LNQwBzOAB84GPAFteaCgF0hACgB0JyBQXRDs%20UtXqtOgJSjdjuAF4AfHBRsqLOABfEFJQDms8UCw2CgM3YlJSLAALKmgjfnh3YWDSYJI4ABI2ADMSg38ZOSpFFTVNbQp4gtIWNHA0ejgUtIyCUX9dAvzSYowKliqbOvtGgBo4UEhwcF5IUHFDNy8fPxZmxO7U9MyBll0PReXV9fFhkKK0DSosCama23qHCgWyM0gNJY4ABBCgUSBcAA81g%20MwaOk8B0SVHKPRO-UGSMOaL60DOumMJj%204MBbgA9GSQXBoJRmAEzApNJgsHANAQWWgXskdHBkpB0HBIN08GQOt0uGQGDE%20Aw-rA0AFooLGGhZOR-hpOjojC0gvd8mgAB5kGIssIYNWoZn4LJqNAAd0QVuwNriQA)

Comment: But this case has an eslint error 'args' is defined but never used.(no-unused-vars). I don't want to remove no-unused-vars setting.

Comment: can you share a Playground with this error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how can I set ESLint to Playground. I'm sorry...